# Rails: Rename model in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model named Subscriber and everytime I create a new subscriber I redirect to the Subscriber#Show page and the url is shown as localhost:3000/subscribers/id in the browser. I want to change the url to show localhost:3000/registered/id instead. I want to do this without changing the Subscriber model name.

In my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :subscribers, :only => [:new, :create, :show]
```

How do I change the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:path`:

```
resources :subscribers, :path => "registered", :only => [:new, :create, :show]
```